# Downloading attachment from Exchange message with Perl

Tags: perl, download, exchange-server

I am automatically downloading mails from an Exchange 2010 server via perl. So far I have managed to access the message via Exchange Web Services (EWS) and parse headers. Now I wonder how I can download the attachments of a message to a local temporary folder.

I am new to Perl language and cannot find the source code or documentation for the message data structure. Any help is appreciated.

```
use Email::Folder::Exchange;
use Email::Simple;

# some more code here....

my $folder = Email::Folder::Exchange->new($url, $user, $pass);

for my $message ($folder->messages) {
    if ($message->header('Subject') =~ /Downloadable Message/) {
        // How to access message's attachments?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the trick is to convert the Email::Simple to Email::MIME and use Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper to parse through each attachment. Easy ;-)

! I only copied the relevant parts... so you might need to extend it a little for reuse.

```
use Email::Folder::Exchange;
use Email::Simple;
use Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper;

# some more code here....

my $folder = Email::Folder::Exchange->new($url, $user, $pass);

for my $message ($folder->messages) {
    my $tmpMsg = Email::MIME->new($message->as_string);
    my $stripper = Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper->new($tmpMsg);

    for my $a ($stripper->attachments()) {
        next if $a->{'filename'} !~ /csv/i; #only csv attachments
        my $tempdir = "C:\\temp\\";
        my $tmpPath = $tmpdir . $a->{'filename'};


        # Save file to temporary path
        my $f = new IO::File $tmpPath, "w" or die "Cannot create file " . $tmpPath;
        print $f $a->{'payload'};
    }
 }
```